# Can the ErrorCode & SQLState combination be considered a unique ID for some exception?

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, error-code

In general, considering ErrorCode & SQLState combination to be a unique ID for a specific exception, is it a safe thing to base your code logic on?

Also to be more specific, Does DataDirect follow such a thing?

Also for an exact case which is what I need,
My code is generation the following Exception:

`[SQLServer JDBC Driver]Changing the default holdability is not supported...`

and the following:

```
System.out.println(">e.getErrorCode: " + e.getErrorCode());
System.out.println(">e.getSQLState: " + e.getSQLState());
```

is returing:

```
>e.getErrorCode:  0
>e.getSQLStat: hy000
```

So would it be safe to assume that if I check for `0 && hy00` then I'm filtering only the exception I mentioned earlier?

It would be very helpful if I can get a reference to an official DataDirect documentation that stating such facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot assume this. SQLState `HY000` is simply a generic CLI SQL error (as defined by the SQL CLI standard), and errorcode 0 means 'no specific error code was set'. Usually drivers use `HY000` as the SQLState when nothing more specific is available, or if the developer didn't bother the specify anything else.

And even in general a single SQLState can cover a very broad range of errors, and whether a single error code (other than 0) is used for one error or a group of errors might depend on the database and on the context of the error.